# Differences between Canvas Property and Margin

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

There are any differences between using `SetValue` with (for example) `Canvas.LeftProperty` and `Margin` Property?

To be more clear:

```
<Canvas>
   <Rectangle x:Name="rect">                         
</Canvas>
```

Is

```
rect.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 10)
```

equivalent to

```
rect.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0)
```

or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Margin property is used with every element to determine extra space around the object.  It works in almost all types of layouting (StackPanel, Grid, ContentControls, etc.)

The Canvas.LeftProperty (as well as Top, Right, and Bottom) only apply to elements which are directly inside a Canvas.  The Canvas will use these values to determine where an object should be.  With Shape elements like a Path, the Canvas also looks at the location data of the Shape when determining the position.

Technically, the Canvas attached properties should accumulate with the inherent location data of a Shape (if any) as well as the Margin.  You could use all 3 to modify the position.  But usually you would try to keep it simple.

For example, a Rectangle should use its Width and Height properties as well as Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top.  A Path would either just rely on its point data or it would offset it with Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top.  You shouldn't use margin for elements inside a Canvas since you have better control without using it, but you technically could.

Answer (score 1):

It looks same but in first case canvas moves you `rect` right in `10` point. In second `rect` moves right in `10` point.

Use one of this way according to your purposes.

**EDIT:** If look more deeply in WPF code. In first case `rect` is moved in [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx) of Canvas in second case in [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx) of Rectangle.

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference (if there's one)?

Answer (score 1):

For an element directly in a `Canvas`, the only difference is in the means. The end result is exactly the same.

When the `Rectangle` is positioned, the layout engine will add together all the values that affect its position. For the `X` coordinate this includes `Canvas.Left` and `Margin.Left`.

So in one case it is adding `10 + 0`, and in the other it is adding `0 + 10`.

So go with whichever you prefer. Personally I prefer `Canvas.Left` in this situation as it seems to make more contextual sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
Canvas.Left
Canvas.Right
Canvas.Top
Canvas.Bottom
```

are enforced only inside the canvas container, they will not alter the width and height of your the control they're being attached to. (left=10, right=10 will not stretch to give a margin of 10 on each side)

```
Margin.Left
Margin.Right
Margin.Top
Margin.Bottom
```

Is controlled by the object that it's been set on, it will work outside of a Canvas on a grid for example and will alter the width and height of any control to enforce it's value (IF the width and height are NaN).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property inside your template of the object using a TemplateBinding or regular Binding as it is a DependencyProperty. This also adjusts the width and height of the object.

The Canvas properties are attached properties to the FrameworkElement and allow positioning of elements that might not have a Margin property. And they do not work if the object does not have a Canvas parent.